# Unknown error when running the project

Tags: solidity, javascript, dapps, nodejs, ethereumjs

While deploying my application, I get the following error. I have tried some solutions but none has worked.

Link to the code repository: https://github.com/Demiladekusa/Evoting-dapp

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Any help with the issue is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem related to Ethereum. Try with older/newer node versions. Otherwise you can ask the repository developer which version they are using.